# How to implement some trainable parameters in the model of Keras like nn.Parameters() in Pytorch?

Tags: keras, parameters, pytorch

I just wanna to implement some trainable parameters in my model with Keras. In Pytorch, we can do it by using torch.nn.Parameter() like below:

```
self.a = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(8))
self.b = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(16,8))
```

I think by doing this in pytorch it can add some trainable parameters into the model. And now I wanna to know, how to achieve similar operations in keras？
Any suggestions or advice are welcomed!

THX! :)

p.s. I just write a custom layer in Keras as below:

```
class Mylayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self,input_dim,output_dim,**kwargs):
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(Mylayer,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='pi',
                                      shape=(self.input_dim,self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='zeros',
                                      trainable=True)
        self.kernel_2 = self.add_weight(name='mean',
                                        shape=(self.input_dim,self.output_dim),
                                        initializer='ones',
                                        trainable=True)

        super(Mylayer,self).build()

    def call(self,x):
        return x,self.kernel,self.kernel_2
```

and I wanna to know if I haven't change the tensor which pass through the layer, should I write the function `def compute_output_shape()` for necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the trainable weights in a custom layer:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, my_args, **kwargs):
        #do whatever you need with my_args

        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs) 

    #you create the weights in build:
    def build(self, input_shape):
        #use the input_shape to infer the necessary shapes for weights
        #use self.whatever_you_registered_in_init to help you, like units, etc. 

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=the_shape_you_calculated,
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)

        #create as many weights as necessary for this layer

        #build the layer - equivalent to self.built=True
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    #create the layer operation here
    def call(self, inputs):
        #do whatever operations are needed
        #example:
        return inputs * self.kernel #make sure the shapes are compatible

    #tell keras about the output shape of your layer
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        #calculate the output shape based on the input shape and your layer's rules
        return calculated_output_shape
```

Now use your layer in the model.

---

If you are using eager execution on with tensorflow and creating a custom training loop, you can work pretty much the same way you do with PyTorch, and you can create weights outside layers with `tf.Variable`, passing them as parameters to the gradient calculation methods.

Comment: Thank you! I guess maybe I should use the custom layers in Keras to do so.

Comment: And I still have two questions: 1) if I want the custom layers don't have any operations on the tensor throughout the model, but create a new trainable parameters(e.g. a tensor/weighted vector), can I use the above way to implement it?2) I think using tf.variable is clear and compact, but if my model is Keras(using TensorFlow backend), can I use this method to build a trainable model directly?

Comment: You can. You can hack the layer to either `return inputs, self.kernel` (the inputs pass through the layer without any change, and you get the kernel as well). Or you can maybe create a dummy input to pass to the layer like `dummy_input = Input(tensor=tf.Variable(1))`, just discard this input inside `call`.

Comment: You can use `tf.Variable` if you are using eager mode on and create your custom training loop. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Comment: OK, I just put a new code above, can you help me to answer the question?

Comment: You should write `def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape): return input_shape, (self.input_dim,self.output_dim), (self.input_dim,self.output_dim)`.

Comment: Could you give an example, How to write the same layer in Pytorch? I am coming from Tf background and need to write a similar layer in Pytorch.

Comment: @AadityaUra, I believe you don't need a layer in PyTorch, just create the trainable tensor and tell the optimizer that the tensor should have its gradient computed. I believe a good PYTorch tutorial will teach that.

Comment: @DanielMöller Please check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952767/custom-layer-from-keras-to-pytorch

Comment: @DanielMöller I'm also having similar doubt, I'm converting a pytorch script into tensorflow.         
`self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(in_channels, out_channels))
        if bias:
            
self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_channels))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
        self.reset_parameters()` how to use tf.Varibale to convert these lines of pytorch's code? I tried like this, for example `w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.weight = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(w_in, w_out)),trainable=True)`

Comment: @DanielMöller I have also posted a question regarding this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862062/understanding-keras-subclass-method-in-tensorflows-deep-learning-pipeline