# Custom layer from keras to pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

Coming from TensorFlow background, I am trying to convert a snippet of code of the custom layer from Keras to PyTorch.

The custom layer in Keras looks like this:

```
class Attention_module(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, class_num):
        super(Attention_module,self).__init__(class_num)
        self.class_num = class_num
        self.Ws = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        embedding_length = int(input_shape[2])

        self.Ws = self.add_weight(shape=(self.class_num, embedding_length),
                                  initializer=tf.keras.initializers.get('glorot_uniform'), trainable=True)

        super(Attention_module, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):

        sentence_trans = tf.transpose(inputs, [0, 2, 1])
        at = tf.matmul(self.Ws, sentence_trans)
        at = tf.math.tanh(at)
        at = K.exp(at - K.max(at, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
        at = at / K.sum(at, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        v = K.batch_dot(at, inputs)

        return v
```

I want to implement the same in the torch; I have already done the forward pass block but am confused about how to do the embedding and weight initialization the same as the above layer in PyTorch?

```
class Attention_module(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, class_num):

        # how to initialize weight with same as above keras layer?

    def forward(self, inputs):
        
        sentence_trans = inputs.permute(0, 2, 1)

        at = torch.mm(self.Ws, sentence_trans)
        at = torch.nn.Tanh(at)
        at = torch.exp(at - torch.max(torch.Tensor(at), dim=-1, keepdims=True).values)
        at = at / torch.sum(at, dim = -1, keepdims=True)
        v = torch.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', at, inputs)

        return v
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Attention_module(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, class_num, input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.class_num = class_num
        embedding_length = int(input_shape[2])
        self.Ws = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=class_num, 
                                     embedding_dim=embedding_length)  # Embedding layer
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.Ws.weight) # Glorot initialization
```

[Here's the reference for layer initialization methods.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html) Xavier init is another name for Glorot init.

The `_` at the end of `torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_` is a pytorch convention that signifies an inplace operation.

You can also use `torch.nn.init` at runtime. It doesn't have to be within `__init__()`. Like:

```
att = Attention_module(class_num, input_shape)
torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(att.Ws.weight)
```

or :

```
for param in att.parameters():
    torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(param)
```

Comment: Hi, It's giving error
`AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call`

Comment: @AadityaUra I have edited the answer. It was missing a `super().__init__()` and `.weight` in initilization line.

Comment: If i am trying this input `input_v = torch.Tensor(np.random.uniform(3,8,[4,2,2]))
rt = Attention_module(12,input_v .shape)(torch.Tensor(input_v))` it's giving error

Comment: The error is `RuntimeError: mat2 must be a matrix`

Comment: Not sure if i understand what this line does from your code. `at = torch.mm(self.Ws, sentence_trans)` . `self.Ws` is an embedding layer and not a tensor. You have to pass token_ids to the embedding layer to get a tensor. Or if you are trying to access the weight of the layer you can use `self.Ws.weight.T` ?