# Understanding Keras subclass method in Tensorflow's deep learning pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a model in tensorflow using the keras subclasses method.

Q1) I am correctly calling layers as `layers = []` and then using `layers.append(GTLayer....)` ?

Q2) calling GTLayer  in **init** of GTN will run class GTLayer and will it call self.conv1 (which will return a tensor A from GTNconv) and self.conv2 (which will again return a tensor A from GTNconv)and then start the `call` mrthod of GTLayer to `H,W` , Am I right?

Q3) What happens to the returned `H and W`  from 'Q2' will it store in `layers[]` list ? and then when we further call the GTNs `call` method it will bring up those layer? Am I correct?

Q4)Later in the `GTN`s `call` method I had to implement linear layers and thus I defined `model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()` and after theat initialised `self.linear1` and `self.linear2`, this way I have implemented subclassing and sequential both! Is that correct?

Q5) I will finally get `loss, y, Ws` from calling GTN , now if I assign my `model = GTN(arguments..)` how will I do the training and back-propagation steps? using an optimiser and loss function? will it follow `model.compile()` and `model.fit` ? Or can we make it any different in the sub-classing method of keras?

```
  import tensorflow as tf
  from tensorflow import keras
  from tensorflow.keras import layers

class GTN(layers.Layer):     
    def __init__(self, num_edge, num_channels,num_layers,norm):
        super(GTN, self).__init__()
        self.num_edge = num_edge
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.is_norm = norm
        
        layers = []
        for i in tf.range(num_layers):
            if i == 0:
                layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=True))
            else:
                layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=False)) 

        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        self.loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        self.linear1 = model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.w_out, input_shape=(self.w_out*self.num_channels,), activation=None)) 
        self.linear2 = model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_class, input_shape=(self.w_out,), activation=None))

   def gcn_conv(self,X,H):
       X = tf.matmul(X, self.weight)
       H = self.norm(H, add=True)
       return tf.matmul(tf.transpose(H),X)
    
   def call(self, A, X, target_x, target):
        A = tf.expand_dims(A, 0)
        Ws = []
        
        for i in range(self.num_layers):
                H = self.normalization(H)
                H, W = self.layers[i](A, H)
            Ws.append(W)
            
        for i in range(self.num_channels):

                X_tmp = tf.nn.relu(self.gcn_conv(X,H[i])).numpy()
                X_ = tf.concat((X_,X_tmp), dim=1)
        
        X_ = self.linear1(X_)
        X_ = tf.nn.relu(X_).numpy()
        y = self.linear2(X_[target_x])
        loss = self.loss(y, target)
        return loss, y, Ws


class GTLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

   def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, first=True):
      super(GTLayer, self).__init__()
      self.in_channels = in_channels
      self.out_channels = out_channels

      self.conv1 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)
      self.conv2 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)

   def call(self, A, H_=None):
        a = self.conv1(A)
        b = self.conv2(A)          
        H = tf.matmul( a, b)
        W = [tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.softmax(self.conv1.weight, axis=1).numpy()),
             tf.stop_gradient(tf.nn.softmax(self.conv2.weight, axis=1).numpy()) ]
    return H,W


class GTConv(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(GTConv, self).__init__()   
    
    def call(self, A):
        A = tf.add_n(tf.nn.softmax(self.weight))
        return A
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer in a week, mention me in the comments, unfortunately I cannot analyse the question at this moment.

Comment: @DanielMöller , May you kindly look at my question and help me out! I posted a better detailed aspect of the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972765/using-keras-layers-how-to-add-weights-of-subclass-layer-into-the-weights-of-the

Comment: @DanielMöller basically the current code is giving this error! while calculating the tape gradient! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949560/tensorflow-tape-gradient-not-able-to-compute-the-grads-and-gives-none-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Q1

No. There are two possibilities here

**1 - If you want to access a standard `layers` property of Keras models:**

- Only `Model` has a `layers` property, a `keras.layers.Layer` doesn't have this property
- You are not supposed to mess with the `layers` property of a `Model`, you should just read it
- The variable you are creating named `layers` is not a property of your class because you did not use `self.layers`.

**2 - If you just want a list named `layers` for personal use in your class:**

- I recommend you don't use a standard name like this and change it to `myLayers` or something like that to avoid confusion.
- The variable `layers` you created is not being used anywhere else in your code, you just created it and never used.
- Remember that `layers = []` just creates a local variable, while `self.layers = []` creates a property in your class that can be used in other methods inside your class

#### Q2

You are not "calling" `GTLayer`, you are "creating" `GTLayer`. This means that you are running `GTLayer.__init__()`.

This distinction is important in Keras:

- This is "creating" a layer: `layer_instance = GTLayer(...)`, which runs `__init__`
- This is "calling" a layer: `layer_instance(input_tensors)`, which runs `__call__` (which will eventually run `call` as defined by you)

You can do both in the same line as `output_tensors = GTLayer(...)(input_tensors)`

So, this is happening in `GTN.__init__`:

- You are "creating" two instances of the `GTLayer`.
- This runs `GTLayer.__init__()` for each instance
- This hits the lines `self.conv1 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)` and `self.conv2 = GTConv(in_channels, out_channels)`
- This is also "creating" (not "calling") `GTConv`.
- `self.conv1` and `self.conv2` are "Layer" instances, not tensors.

#### Q3

No tensor is produced here because you never "called" any layer in `GTN.__init__()`.
(And this is ok. Usually, you "create" layers inside `__init__()` and "call" layers inside `call`.)

Your `layers` local variable will have "instances of `GTLayer`".

#### Q4

You mixed two approaches in a strange way.
You can, of course, use a `Sequential` model if you want, but it's not necessary, and you're not using it correcly.

If in `call` you are calling each layer (that is `X_ = self.linear1(X_)` and `y = self.linear2(X_[target_x])`), you don't need a `Sequential` model at all, and you can just have the following in `GTN.__init__()` (this is the best approach for subclassing):

```
self.linear1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.w_out, input_shape=(self.w_out*self.num_channels,), activation=None)
self.linear2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_class, input_shape=(self.w_out,), activation=None)
```

But you could have `self.submodel = Sequential(...)` and then use `self.submodel` in `GTN.call()`. But having a `Model` inside a layer sounds weird and might cause some strange behavior in specific cases. And, of course, the ReLUs should be a part of this submodel.

#### Q5

**I will finally get `loss, y, Ws` from calling GTN**

That loss and weights coming from `call` is a "very very" strange thing. I never saw this and I don't understand why you're doing it this way. This is not standard use of Keras and only in very specific and otherwise unsolvable cases you'd try something like this. I cannot say it will work.

**How will I do the training and back-propagation steps?**

You should have implemented a `keras.models.Model`, not a `keras.layers.Layer`. Only models have the ability to compile and train.

Usually, you'd not create a loss in call, you'd create a loss in `model.compile`, unless you're dealing with unconventional losses, like weight or activity regularization, things that really depend on the layer and not on the model's inputs/outputs.

#### Extra tips

There is no need to create custom layers if you're not going to create custom trainable weights. It's not wrong, of course, but also not necessary. It can help organize your code, or just add extra complication.

You are trying to use `weight` from your layers, but you never defined any weight anywhere.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to achieve what you want, but I don't know what you want (and that would be something for another question, I think...)

This might be a good reading for subclassing: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models?hl=en

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply! For your question, I will invoke `class GTN` by `model = GTN(arg...)` and then train the weights which I have defined in the various method of classes `GTN` and `GTConv` , I see that I missed the initial definition of `self.weight` in `GTN` class init method.

Comment: But my question is, as you may see I call class `GTLayer` in `GTN` and class `GTConv` in `GTLayer` ; so will the weights defined in `GTConv` reflect in my `model.trainable_weights` list? . Infact will `model.trainable_weights` work with class `GTN`? As I have inherited `GTN` from keras.Layers!

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, but I believe it will work, but GNT must be a `Model`, not a `Layer`. And you don't need to output weights and loss like that. That is strange, you only do that if you have a very specific purpose in mind, and your explanation doesn't seem any different from standard training.

Comment: I tried your ideas from the couple of answers which you gave me, I have tried to showcase an example of my code, in this colab link . At the moment there are some errors while computing the gradients , don't know why they still appear! Mind checking this link, great help! https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cobDJTVI8QzpHeMVUrEQgY1ACdUwZuz5?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnshumanSinha , I made some comments in your colab, but I didn't analyse the entire code, so some things might be inaccurate, but I believe I pointed out many possible sources of None gradients.

Comment: Hey, Daniel ; that's great help. I'm able t resolve all the errors from your comments. The code now functions well, I have added a validation and testing code lines, but I'm not sure if they are correct. May you kindly look at the colab link once to validate! Additionaly, in pytorch we usually write `with torch.no_grad():` before calculating the validation and test case ; how to implement this line in tensorflow?

Comment: You don't use a gradient tape. Some layers also need `training=False` when you call them. with a value tensor. Since you created non-standard `call` signature, I think it's harder, otherwise you could simply call your model with `training=False`.

Comment: Okay, got it. I have assigned them as `training = True`; but what happens when we access the same variables for `validation` and `testing`? In these cases I don't wish to include them in the computational graph. I just wish to calculate the results.  e.g `val_loss,y_valid,_ = model(A, node_features_val, val_node, val_target)` ; If I write this line of code, it will again add to the computational graph. But I don't wish to do that; In pytorch we use `with torch.no_grad(): { line of code 1, line of code 2..} ` to separate them from the computational graph.

Comment: You should include `Training` in your call and do the calculations or not based on that.

Comment: I could not understand your comment. Kindly check my colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cobDJTVI8QzpHeMVUrEQgY1ACdUwZuz5?usp=sharing#scrollTo=DEe7KW_x3lYj

Comment: When I write `val_loss,y_valid,_ = model(A, node_features_val, val_node, val_target)` and `
        test_loss, y_test,W = model(A, node_features_test, test_node, test_target)` ? How to implement the training to be false for these two lines?

Comment: Add it in the `call` signature and skip whatever you want to skip when it's true.

Comment: Okay great! Also found help from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320371/what-does-training-true-mean-when-calling-a-tensorflow-keras-model

Comment: Added the 'Training` keyword in `def call(self, A, X, target_x, target, Training=True):` and wrote        `val_loss,y_valid,_ = model(A, node_features_val, val_node, val_target, Training=False)` and
       ` test_loss, y_test,W = model(A, node_features_test, test_node, test_target, Training=False)` instead of the previous lines.