# Tensorflow `tape.gradient` not able to compute the grads and gives 'None' value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make a keras model with the subclassing method. While training the model, I wish to optimise the gradient based loss term but I'm not able to compute the grads in my code. For reference to `model = GTN(..)` kindly open my github link : [link](https://github.com/anshumansinha16/GTN_Gatech/blob/main/model_tf_3.py)

I have also shown the error message at the bottom. Can someone please help me finding a solution to this error! Kindly ask me for any reference if needed!

```
        model = GTN(num_edge=A.shape[-1],
                            num_channels=num_channels,
                            w_in = node_features.shape[1],
                            w_out = node_dim,
                            num_class=num_classes,
                            num_layers=num_layers,
                            norm=norm)
        
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)

            
        for i in range(epochs):

            print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (i,))

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                
                loss,y_train,Ws = model(A, node_features, train_node, train_target)
              
                train_f1 = tf.reduce_mean(f1_score(tf.math.argmax(y_train, 1), train_target, num_classes=num_classes)).cpu().numpy() 
                
                print('Train - Loss: {}, Macro_F1: {}'.format(loss.cpu().numpy(), train_f1))

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
            
            
            print('\n tw_loss', loss)
            print('\n tw', len(model.trainable_weights))
            print('tw',model.trainable_weights)
            print('\n grads',grads)
            print('\n\n')
            
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

**Error:**

```
Start of epoch 0 /Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/GTN_gatech/model_tf_4.py:90: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide   deg_inv = (1/deg) WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/GTN_gatech/main.py:149:
_EagerTensorBase.cpu (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.identity instead. Train - Loss: 651, Macro_F1: 0.4 WARNING:tensorflow:The dtype of the target tensor must be floating (e.g. tf.float32) when calling GradientTape.gradient, got tf.int64

 tw_loss tf.Tensor(651, shape=(), dtype=int64)

 tw 6 tw [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(334, 64) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[-6.8065554e-02,  1.7808577e-02, -3.3060413e-02, ...,
        -7.9445476e-03,  2.2907598e-02, -5.0616432e-05],
       [ 8.3083950e-02,  3.4094580e-02, -9.1628522e-02, ...,
         8.4636576e-02, -3.2849174e-02,  3.9851848e-02],
       [-5.1332596e-03,  1.8217593e-02, -1.5915236e-02, ...,
         3.9537903e-02,  1.8487601e-02, -2.5786100e-02],
       ...,
       [-5.0101068e-02, -4.0382389e-02,  2.7463108e-02, ...,
        -2.8208895e-02,  4.4236373e-02,  1.3420659e-02],
       [ 5.8705002e-02, -2.6983086e-02, -2.2525910e-02, ...,
         6.6656552e-02, -3.7147861e-02, -3.6436077e-02],
       [-5.7043720e-02, -2.9050818e-02, -4.8337817e-02, ...,
         6.1437004e-04, -8.8474199e-02, -2.4155889e-02]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy= array([ 0.04898109,  0.02743905,  0.01275807, -0.01279561,
-0.03094534,
       -0.00206327,  0.02396646, -0.06562269, -0.0101589 , -0.02339233,
        0.02572307, -0.00181847, -0.05587135,  0.00757567,  0.02006881,
        0.01461728,  0.028289  , -0.05815926,  0.01005831,  0.05460797,
       -0.02772039, -0.07411575,  0.03479945,  0.06263794, -0.03662011,
        0.03893709,  0.02438426,  0.07506319, -0.05003419, -0.04925965,
       -0.03095563, -0.01559789,  0.06570208, -0.01362679, -0.04528281,
       -0.02255867,  0.01575551, -0.02482953, -0.04452832, -0.03946757,
        0.06436181,  0.03763793,  0.02348374, -0.03043802, -0.01731209,
        0.00422201,  0.03273699, -0.05148602,  0.01378352, -0.03534586,
       -0.00879145, -0.03751075, -0.07239651,  0.03782724, -0.07762406,
        0.06534646, -0.01509482, -0.06328102,  0.04470748,  0.08636095,
        0.04614442, -0.00683495,  0.07316597,  0.07798533], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense/kernel:0' shape=(128, 64) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.02660406,  0.1400717 ,  0.0716072 , ...,  0.03762217,
        -0.11936574,  0.10648988],
       [ 0.13989542, -0.06696923, -0.08287655, ..., -0.15777484,
         0.04509974,  0.03066735],
       [-0.02768627, -0.11512892, -0.15029587, ...,  0.13351665,
         0.06349541, -0.13801941],
       ...,
       [-0.04386559, -0.04851469, -0.08838961, ...,  0.10856901,
         0.01087596,  0.15492262],
       [-0.12869178, -0.1252187 , -0.00052148, ..., -0.09987513,
         0.10923143, -0.17052075],
       [ 0.11575021,  0.16109909,  0.07039063, ..., -0.00092761,
         0.14228679,  0.04648393]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy= array([0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(64, 1) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.02259868],
       [-0.2360486 ],
       [ 0.1571801 ],
       [-0.25825864],
       [ 0.21658659],
       [-0.10407236],
       [-0.14186335],
       [-0.16689046],
       [ 0.00348559],
       [ 0.04536584],
       [-0.09497032],
       [-0.05356446],
       [-0.282526  ],
       [ 0.15660894],
       [ 0.21695083],
       [-0.08959688],
       [-0.11758406],
       [-0.00246018],
       [ 0.03585082],
       [-0.11885171],
       [ 0.11711046],
       [ 0.2112925 ],
       [ 0.06549275],
       [ 0.04496366],
       [-0.016817  ],
       [-0.28353626],
       [-0.08626364],
       [-0.03050202],
       [-0.00700936],
       [ 0.13813066],
       [ 0.13015306],
       [ 0.07458067],
       [ 0.03156129],
       [-0.15235806],
       [ 0.23973352],
       [ 0.0828113 ],
       [ 0.0805389 ],
       [ 0.21249765],
       [-0.1350545 ],
       [ 0.18923104],
       [ 0.11602828],
       [-0.13561219],
       [-0.11290435],
       [-0.2054773 ],
       [-0.08924933],
       [-0.01811975],
       [-0.15017524],
       [ 0.06316456],
       [-0.03752789],
       [ 0.04196835],
       [ 0.26935464],
       [ 0.01272258],
       [-0.16718239],
       [-0.2080706 ],
       [-0.09847307],
       [ 0.12414747],
       [ 0.13261127],
       [ 0.05679142],
       [ 0.25509387],
       [-0.02078632],
       [-0.24836813],
       [-0.06382808],
       [ 0.05103779],
       [-0.13789822]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]

 grads [None, None, None, None, None, None]



Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/GTN_gatech/main.py", line 162, in <module>
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))   File "/Users/anshumansinha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 633, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)   File "/Users/anshumansinha/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 73, in filter_empty_gradients
    raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. " ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'gtn/dense/kernel:0', 'gtn/dense/bias:0', 'gtn/dense_1/kernel:0', 'gtn/dense_1/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(334, 64) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[-6.8065554e-02, 
1.7808577e-02, -3.3060413e-02, ...,
        -7.9445476e-03,  2.2907598e-02, -5.0616432e-05],
       [ 8.3083950e-02,  3.4094580e-02, -9.1628522e-02, ...,
         8.4636576e-02, -3.2849174e-02,  3.9851848e-02],
       [-5.1332596e-03,  1.8217593e-02, -1.5915236e-02, ...,
         3.9537903e-02,  1.8487601e-02, -2.5786100e-02],
       ...,
       [-5.0101068e-02, -4.0382389e-02,  2.7463108e-02, ...,
        -2.8208895e-02,  4.4236373e-02,  1.3420659e-02],
       [ 5.8705002e-02, -2.6983086e-02, -2.2525910e-02, ...,
         6.6656552e-02, -3.7147861e-02, -3.6436077e-02],
       [-5.7043720e-02, -2.9050818e-02, -4.8337817e-02, ...,
         6.1437004e-04, -8.8474199e-02, -2.4155889e-02]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy= array([ 0.04898109,  0.02743905,  0.01275807,
-0.01279561, -0.03094534,
       -0.00206327,  0.02396646, -0.06562269, -0.0101589 , -0.02339233,
        0.02572307, -0.00181847, -0.05587135,  0.00757567,  0.02006881,
        0.01461728,  0.028289  , -0.05815926,  0.01005831,  0.05460797,
       -0.02772039, -0.07411575,  0.03479945,  0.06263794, -0.03662011,
        0.03893709,  0.02438426,  0.07506319, -0.05003419, -0.04925965,
       -0.03095563, -0.01559789,  0.06570208, -0.01362679, -0.04528281,
       -0.02255867,  0.01575551, -0.02482953, -0.04452832, -0.03946757,
        0.06436181,  0.03763793,  0.02348374, -0.03043802, -0.01731209,
        0.00422201,  0.03273699, -0.05148602,  0.01378352, -0.03534586,
       -0.00879145, -0.03751075, -0.07239651,  0.03782724, -0.07762406,
        0.06534646, -0.01509482, -0.06328102,  0.04470748,  0.08636095,
        0.04614442, -0.00683495,  0.07316597,  0.07798533], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense/kernel:0' shape=(128, 64) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.02660406,  0.1400717 ,  0.0716072 , ...,  0.03762217,
        -0.11936574,  0.10648988],
       [ 0.13989542, -0.06696923, -0.08287655, ..., -0.15777484,
         0.04509974,  0.03066735],
       [-0.02768627, -0.11512892, -0.15029587, ...,  0.13351665,
         0.06349541, -0.13801941],
       ...,
       [-0.04386559, -0.04851469, -0.08838961, ...,  0.10856901,
         0.01087596,  0.15492262],
       [-0.12869178, -0.1252187 , -0.00052148, ..., -0.09987513,
         0.10923143, -0.17052075],
       [ 0.11575021,  0.16109909,  0.07039063, ..., -0.00092761,
         0.14228679,  0.04648393]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy= array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(64, 1) dtype=float32, numpy= array([[ 0.02259868],
       [-0.2360486 ],
       [ 0.1571801 ],
       [-0.25825864],
       [ 0.21658659],
       [-0.10407236],
       [-0.14186335],
       [-0.16689046],
       [ 0.00348559],
       [ 0.04536584],
       [-0.09497032],
       [-0.05356446],
       [-0.282526  ],
       [ 0.15660894],
       [ 0.21695083],
       [-0.08959688],
       [-0.11758406],
       [-0.00246018],
       [ 0.03585082],
       [-0.11885171],
       [ 0.11711046],
       [ 0.2112925 ],
       [ 0.06549275],
       [ 0.04496366],
       [-0.016817  ],
       [-0.28353626],
       [-0.08626364],
       [-0.03050202],
       [-0.00700936],
       [ 0.13813066],
       [ 0.13015306],
       [ 0.07458067],
       [ 0.03156129],
       [-0.15235806],
       [ 0.23973352],
       [ 0.0828113 ],
       [ 0.0805389 ],
       [ 0.21249765],
       [-0.1350545 ],
       [ 0.18923104],
       [ 0.11602828],
       [-0.13561219],
       [-0.11290435],
       [-0.2054773 ],
       [-0.08924933],
       [-0.01811975],
       [-0.15017524],
       [ 0.06316456],
       [-0.03752789],
       [ 0.04196835],
       [ 0.26935464],
       [ 0.01272258],
       [-0.16718239],
       [-0.2080706 ],
       [-0.09847307],
       [ 0.12414747],
       [ 0.13261127],
       [ 0.05679142],
       [ 0.25509387],
       [-0.02078632],
       [-0.24836813],
       [-0.06382808],
       [ 0.05103779],
       [-0.13789822]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'gtn/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>)).
```

Comment: In many places you convert your tensors into numpy arrays using `.numpy()`. As soon as you do that, there will be no gradients based on these tensors. Try to use tensorflow tensors everywhere (i.e. remove all `.numpy()` calls inside your model) and then try again.

Comment: @André Are you talking about the `GTN` code? In the model link? Or in the code snippet shown above?

Comment: The GTN code, [for instance here](https://github.com/anshumansinha16/GTN_Gatech/blob/main/model_tf_3.py#L121). But there are many many places where you do this and, in my opinion, shouldn't.

Comment: I tried to run the code without `.numpy()` here, and got the following error `File "/Users/anshumansinha/Desktop/GTN_gatech/model_tf_4.py", line 134, in call
    y = self.linear2(X_[target_x])
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "gtn" (type GTN).

Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: shape=(800,), dtype=int64, `

Comment: The new error seems to be related to this `X_[target_x]`, where `target_x` is trying to make slices of the tensor `X_`. You cannot do this if `target_x` is a TF tensor. But you cannot make it numpy if it must participate in backpropagation. Then you should look for some tf functions like `tf.gather` and its "see also" section in the documentation.